# Errors writing queries that content at least 2 element in an Arrray

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying to write a query that would fetch a list of documents containing at least 2 interests in the array.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
db.students.find({ interest: { $elemMatch: {$eq:"hiking", $eq:"music" } } }).limit(5)
```

The issue is, giving results of student with at least one of the interest.
The objective is to ensure it produces a result that has at least 2 of the interest highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select results containing those 2 fields you should use $all instead of $elemMatch:

```
db.collection.find({
  interest: {
    $all: [
      "hiking",
      "music"
    ]
  }
})
```